# relation "forum_forum" does not exist - Django Machina

Tags: python, django, django-machina

I've been looking at documentation to install django-machina to use their forum capabilities. After following the quickstart guide I've run into an issue after makemigrations and migrate. relation "forum_forum" does not exist

I've tried looking through the lib files of the package and doesn't seem to be wrong. I've tried to uninstall and reinstall but nothing has been working.

```
"""
Django settings for games_backend project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 5.0.2.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/settings/
"""

from datetime import timedelta
import environ
import os
from pathlib import Path
from decouple import config
from machina import MACHINA_MAIN_STATIC_DIR
from machina import MACHINA_MAIN_TEMPLATE_DIR

env = environ.Env(
    DEBUG=(bool, True)
)
# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent

environ.Env.read_env(BASE_DIR / '.env')
# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'dasdddadsdadadsdd'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['localhost']

CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = [
    'http://localhost:3000',
    
]

CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True

# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
     'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.sitemaps',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django_filters',
    'rest_framework',
    'corsheaders',
    'djoser',
    'games',
    'users',
    # 'forum',
    'storages',

    # Third party apps
    'mptt',
    'haystack',
    'widget_tweaks',

    # Machina apps
    'machina',
    'machina.apps.forum',
    'machina.apps.forum_conversation',
    'machina.apps.forum_conversation.forum_attachments',
    'machina.apps.forum_conversation.forum_polls',
    'machina.apps.forum_feeds',
    'machina.apps.forum_moderation',
    'machina.apps.forum_search',
    'machina.apps.forum_tracking',
    'machina.apps.forum_member',
    'machina.apps.forum_permission',


]


# MIGRATION_MODULES = {
#     'forum_conversation': 'machina.apps.forum_conversation.migrations',
#     'forum_member': 'machina.apps.forum_member.migrations',
#     # 'forum': 'machina.apps.forum.migrations',
# }

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    # Machina
    'machina.apps.forum_permission.middleware.ForumPermissionMiddleware',

]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'games_backend.urls'

# TEMPLATES = [
#     {
#         'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
#         'DIRS': [MACHINA_MAIN_TEMPLATE_DIR,],
#         'APP_DIRS': True,
#         'OPTIONS': {
            
#             'context_processors': [
#                 'django.template.context_processors.debug',
#                 'django.template.context_processors.request',
#                 'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
#                 'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
#                 # Machina
#                 'machina.core.context_processors.metadata',
#             ],
#             #no loaders for machina sicne were using react
         
#         },
#     },
# ]

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': (
            # ...
            MACHINA_MAIN_TEMPLATE_DIR,
        ),
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                # ...
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                # Machina
                'machina.core.context_processors.metadata',
            ],
            'loaders': [
                'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
                'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
            ]
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'games_backend.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/settings/#databases


DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': env('DB_NAME'),
        'USER': env('DB_USER'),
        'PASSWORD': env('DB_PASSWORD'),
        'HOST': env('DB_HOST'),
        'PORT': env('DB_PORT'),
    }
}


EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = env('EMAIL_HOST')
EMAIL_PORT = env('EMAIL_PORT')
EMAIL_HOST_USER = env('EMAIL_HOST_USER')
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = env('EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD')
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True

# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'users.UserAccount'

# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = 'static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'build/static'),
    #machina
    MACHINA_MAIN_STATIC_DIR,
]
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR)

# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'

CORS_ALLOW_ALL_ORIGINS = True

#add our prod backend and igdb domain if still using it to allowed origins
# CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = [
#     "http://localhost:3000",  # React's default port when running locally
#     "https://yourfrontenddomain.com",
# ]
#machina temporary caches for post attachemnts
CACHES = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.locmem.LocMemCache',
    },
    'machina_attachments': {
        'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.filebased.FileBasedCache',
        'LOCATION': '/tmp',
    },
}

#machina haystack for search for forum
HAYSTACK_CONNECTIONS = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'haystack.backends.simple_backend.SimpleEngine',
    },
}
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    ],
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication',
        
    )
    ,
    'DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS': 'games.pagination.CustomPageNumberPagination',
    'PAGE_SIZE': 24,
    'DEFAULT_FILTER_BACKENDS': ['django_filters.rest_framework.DjangoFilterBackend']

}
# DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = "storages.backends.s3.S3Storage"
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = env('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID')
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = env('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY')
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = env('AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME')
AWS_S3_REGION_NAME = env('AWS_S3_REGION_NAME')
AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN = env('AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN') #change removed http://
# CLOUDFRONT_DOMAIN= env('CLOUDFRONT_DOMAIN')


STATIC_LOCATION = "static"
# STATIC_URL = f'{CLOUDFRONT_DOMAIN}/static/'
# STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'django_static.storage_backends.StaticStorage'


SIMPLE_JWT = {
   'AUTH_HEADER_TYPES': ('JWT',),
   'ACCESS_TOKEN_LIFETIME': timedelta(minutes=60),
   'REFRESH_TOKEN_LIFETIME': timedelta(days=7),
   'ROTATE_REFRESH_TOKENS': True,
   'BLACKLIST_AFTER_ROTATION': True,
   'USER_ID_FIELD': 'id',
}

DOMAIN = "localhost:3000"
SITE_NAME = "eList"

DJOSER = {
    'USER_CREATE_PASSWORD_RETYPE': True,
    'USERNAME_CHANGED_EMAIL_CONFIRMATION': True,
    'PASSWORD_CHANGED_EMAIL_CONFIRMATION': True,
    'SEND_CONFIRMATION_EMAIL': True,
    'SET_PASSWORD_RETYPE': True,
    'PASSWORD_RESET_CONFIRM_RETYPE': True,
    'PASSWORD_RESET_CONFIRM_URL': 'password/reset/confirm/{uid}/{token}',
    'USERNAME_RESET_CONFIRM_URL': 'username/reset/confirm/{uid}/{token}',
    'ACTIVATION_URL': 'activate/{uid}/{token}',
    'SEND_ACTIVATION_EMAIL': True,
    'SERIALIZERS': {
        'user_create': 'users.serializers.UserCreateSerializer',
        'user': 'users.serializers.UserAccountSerializer',
        'current_user': 'users.serializers.UserAccountSerializer',
        'user_delete': 'users.serializers.UserDeleteSerializer',
    }
}
```